# Two double quote and line feed in string concatenation

Tags: string, string-concatenation

I have to form a string this way:

```
set value valuefunc(""-Material contents
                      -Material color
                      -Material origin "")
```

I have tried this way:

```
s1=@"set value valuefunc("""""""";------8 double quotes
s2="-Material contents"+Char(10)+"-Material color"+Char(10)+"-Material origin"+Char(10);
s3=@"""""""")";
FinalString="\""+s1+s2+s3+"\"";
```

But it is coming back this way:

```
set value valuefunc("";
            s2 = @"")- Material contents
-Material color
-Material origin
```

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: Store the different quote characters in variables or as constants. Concatenate those together. As it is just appending characters to strings, the compiler / interpreter does not have to deal with `literal quote characters in strings` and does not get confused. It is slightly longer to type out but a lot easier to debug.